# jQuery - calculate width of an element

Tags: jquery, width, element, calculated-columns

I would like to calculate the width of an element (#content) through subtract the width of the window with the width of the navigation. Actually I don't know the failure of my code. Would be great if some could help me!

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var widthWindow = $(window).width();
        var widthNav = $("nav").width();
        $("#content").css({ "width": widthWindow - widthNav });

        // Put the console log here
        console.log(widthWindow, widthNav);
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: What are you getting if you put `console.log(widthWindow, widthNav)` inside the resize event at last?

Comment: `ReferenceError: widthWindow is not defined`

Comment: Have you placed it in the same place as I have placed in your code?

Comment: Now I did, yes. I got this `1262 320` - seems to work! What does your code do exactly? Thanks!

Comment: You can try this: `$("#content").width(widthWindow - widthNav);`

Answer (score 0):

You're not invoking the wrapping function. Plus you're calling the `.resize()` function on itself.

```
(function() {    
    $(window).resize(function () {
    var widthWindow = $(window).width();
    var widthNav = $("nav").width();
    $("#content").width(widthWindow - widthNav); // as suggested by @palash
    });
 })();
```